# Looping through two variables simultaneously

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I have this equation

```
W = W1+W2
```

And I want to write a `for` loop that takes starting values for `W1` and `W2`,
i.e.

```
W1 = 2 W2 = 1.5
```

and add 10 percent to each one each time for 10 times and solve `W = W1 + W2` each time.

For example, the first one would be

```
W = 2+1.5 = 3.5
```

then

```
W = 2.2 + 1.65 = 3.85
```

and so on.

Basically a `for` loop where you are changing two variables, but they change together.

Comment: `W=W1+W2`, `W*(1.1.^(0:10))`?

Comment: @David, what is `1.1`?

Comment: @CroCo it is a number, being one-point-one, i.e. multiplying `W` with this number means adding 10%, as per the OPs request. Best solution on the board here.

Comment: @Adriaan, I know it is a number. Why not just multiply by `.1` since it is 10 percent.

Comment: @CroCo because then you end up with 10 % of the number, not the number + 10%. This is by far the most concise solution here, just a single line. All your looping is correct, but takes a lot of writing and, as Dae said, is much slower than vectorising.

Answer (score 1):

I fully agree with [@David's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33643334/looping-through-two-variables-simultaneously#comment55060649_33643334), vectorising is the way to go here:

```
W1 = 2;W2=1.5;
W=W1+W2;
W*(1.1.^(0:10))
ans =
  Columns 1 through 9
    3.5000    3.8500    4.2350    4.6585    5.1244    5.6368    6.2005    6.8205    7.5026
  Columns 10 through 11
    8.2528    9.0781
```

Answer (score 0):

Good matlab syntax frequently includes finding ways to not use loops. David's answer is an example of this. If you specifically need a for loop, this code does the same this in an overly drawn out and clunky way that doesn't make use of matlab's features or even good math, but I think it's what you asked for.

```
W1 = zeros(1,10);
W1 = 2;
W2 = 1.5;
for i = 1:10
    W(i) = W1 + W2;
    W(i)
    W1 = W1 * 1.1;
    W2 = W2 * 1.1;
end
```

But use David's answer unless you have a good reason not to.

Answer (score 0):

```
clear
clc

W1 = 2;
W2 = 1.5;
for i = 1:10
     W = W1 + W2
    W1 = W1 + W1*0.1;
    W2 = W2 + W2*0.1;
end
```

Comment: It's better not to include the `clear;clc` statement. If the OP copies this in the middle of his program everything suddenly is removed and the program probably crashes.